# How to inhibit button command if button press also set focus?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

My application has a command bound to mouse buttons. I've come to realize it is annoying when you click a window to set focus and it also does the button command.

Here is the line binding my command to button 1:

```
bind .f.canvas <Button-1> {panto %W %x %y 0.5}; # pan half distance
```

How to inhibit invokation of button command when button press is also used to set focus?

---

Here is my "test sequence":

1. Open program
2. Click on canvas. Desired/Result: Pan to clicked position.
3. Click on desktop.
4. Click on canvas. Desired: No pan. Result: Pan to clicked position.
5. Click on canvas. Desired/Result: Pan to clicked position.

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is a bit of a hack. I ride piggy-back on a keyboard focus event on an entry widget, temporarily disabling the button command while entry is not in focus:

```
ttk::entry .f.cmd -textvar e -width 30
bind .f.cmd <FocusOut> {
  puts "focus out, disable button press"; 
  bind .f.canvas <Button-1> {}
}
bind .f.cmd <FocusIn> {
  puts "focus in, enable button press starting next event"; 
  after idle {
    bind .f.canvas <Button-1> {
      panto %%W %%x %%y 0.5
    }
  };
}
```

Tested on Win10, Tcl 8.6.

Comment: I guess you could just check in your `panto` procedure which widget has the focus and do nothing if it isn't the canvas…

Comment: @DonalFellows Problem is the FocusIn event is processed before Button-1, so it will always be true. That is what the `after idle` is for.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your binding script finish with `break`, it will not run any of the other scripts associated with that event (e.g., at the widget class level, the whole window level, or at the whole application level). Concretely, you do this:

```
bind .f.canvas <Button-1> {
    panto %W %x %y 0.5; # pan half distance
    break
}
```

This sort of thing is one of the few cases where multi-command binding scripts are recommended. Usually, it's better (for comprehensibility) to extract things into a procedure, but in this case it's better to put the `break` in directly.

Comment: That does not do what I want. Got a hack solution, will post that and a better description.